# Inquiry over stability of WP 10 on an htc 8s

Tags: 8.0, windows-10-mobile, update, insider-preview

If I download a ''Developer Preview App'' on my htc 8s and check for an update in Feb 2016 am I still going to get windows 8.1 or find that the only update available is windows 10, and if so should i go ahead with a windows 10 update?I have researched only how 8.1 behaves,can WP 10 also be stable on my phone?

Comment: If you're referring to the Preview for Developers app, that's mostly outdated. But it will still give you 8.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/12426/106

Comment: Also related: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/12054/106